# Dynamically changing lightning button icon name with setAttribute not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, button, lwc-dom

I'm trying to change the icon of a lightning button icon but the image isn't changing however I see that the attribute is being updated.

```
 this.template.querySelector('#'+event.target.id).setAttribute("icon-name","utility:check");
```

Answer (score 11):

setAttribute is for setting HTML attributes. For component attributes, use direct assignment:

```
event.target.iconName='utility:check"
```

If you use query selectors, just remember that if it's not an HTML component, use the direct assignment method.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that!

Answer (score 1):

Using track variable is another way to go.

In the javascript controller

```
@track iconname = 'DefaultIconName';

handleToggleIconname(){
  this.iconname = 'NewIconName';
}
```

In the html template file

```
<lightning-icon icon-name={iconname}></lightning-icon>
```

Comment: +1, but note: `@track` is no longer necessary for shallow references, such as a string variable in your answer. You only need to track objects and arrays if you want them to be reactive.